# Возможно ли использовать в теги audio плейлист с песнями от DropBox?

Tags: dropbox, html, html5

Всем привет и с наступающим, один из последних вопросов в этом году у меня звучит так.
Возможно ли использовать в теги audio плейлист с песнями от DropBox?

Comment: у меня не прокатило.

Comment: вот и у меня такая же фигня только по одной песни получаеться подключить

Answer (score 1):

Используйте dropbox api, думаю это реально.

Comment: а подробней можно, просто я так ничего путного и не нашёл в сети